# How to execute an external console application with PowerShell and send the result to email?

Tags: powershell

I need to execute some periodic console applications that give me some results (on the console)... How can I execute it and have its return data sent to my email?
I tried to use [Diagnostics.Process]::Start() and it launches my application but i don't know how to get the return... I do not want the exitCode, I want the text that the application prints on screen.
Using PS V2 CTP3.

*** UPDATE

The solutions presented worked fine but i have a problem... this application that i need to execute is gfix from the firebird database and now i discovered a thing, I can't redirect the output of gfix to a file, if i execute on command prompt the line:

gfix.exe -v -f dabatase.gdb > c:\test.txt

it print the output on the screen and the file is empty. 
Same thing if I try to assign it to a variable... I don't know what difference gfix has from the other console apps that I use, but looks like its output can't be redirected.

Has someone seeing this?

*** UPDATE 2

Even if I use Start-transcript /Stop-Transcript, although on the screen I see the gfix output, on the file there is only the commands :/

*** UPDATE 3

Found the solution here
http://edn.embarcadero.com/br/article/25605

Comment: Is there any reason why to stick to V2 CTP3?

Comment: none, i found CTP3 to download on MS site first :( - will try to find v2 final :)

Comment: This is correct link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Comment: So, you're all set then?  FYI about the start-transcript issue and EXEs: http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2010/01/04/workaround-for-start-transcript-on-native-processes.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
# temporary file
$f = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
# start process and redirect its output to the temp file
ping localhost > $f

# create and send email
$emailFrom = "user@yourdomain.com"
$emailTo = "user@yourdomain.com"
$subject = "results"
$body = (Get-Content $f) -join "`r`n"
$smtpServer = "your smtp server"
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($emailFrom, $emailTo, $subject, $body)

# delete the file
remove-item $f
```

I think in this case `[Diagnostics.Process]::Start()` is not needed. Besides that there is a cmdlet `Start-Process` that does almost the same.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell v2 is now out, so you could consider upgrading.

Then, you can simply try:
PS > [string]$ipconfig=ipconfig
PS > send-mailmessage -to some_email -from from_email -subject PowerShell -body $ipconfig -bodyashtml -smtp my_smtp_server

Now, it depends on how complicated your command-line output is, because the above method will collapse multiple lines into a single on.

Comment: You are right, assignment works as well. So in case that there are more lines, this helps: `$ipconfig = (ipconfig) -join "`r`n"`